# How, in a Jenkins publish session, get past the error "rm: command not found"?

Tags: bash, unix, jenkins, ssh

1. I have `a_version.jar`,`b_version.jar` deployed to server through Jenkins publish over ssh.
2. `a_version.jar` contains `lib/b.jar`
3. Need to remove `b.jar` and replace it with symlink to `b_version.jar`
4. Create symlink to `a_version.jar` and place it in root folder.

Here are the commands I tried in execute command window, with

- `a-version.jar` deployed in `/bin/dist/`;
- symlink to `b-version.jar` deployed in `/bin/b/dist/b.jar`:

---

```
cd /bin/dist/

rm -rf temp
mkdir temp
cd temp

cp /bin/dist/a-${VERSION}.jar .
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/bin
jar -xvf /bin/dist/a-${VERSION}.jar 
cd lib
rm -rf b.jar
cp bin/b/dist/b.jar /bin/dist/temp/lib/
cd /bin/dist/temp/
jar -cvf a-${VERSION}.jar
cp a-${VERSION}.jar  /bin/dist/
ln -s /bin/dist/a-${VERSION}.jar /root/a.jar
exit
```

---

At the `rm -rf b.jar` step, I get `rm command not found`.
And I checked the permission is `rw-r--r--`

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

In order to debug this, try and display the PATH in your script

```
echo Windows PATH %PATH%
echo Linux PATH ${PATH}
```

Depending on which line will actually print something, you will know if you are in CMD or a git bash session.

The OP mentions:

> echo Linux did printed `"Linux PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"`

That means /bin is missing.

Add to the script:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/bin
```

(`rm` is in `/bin/rm`)

Comment: Vonc: thanks for the reply. echo Linux did printed "Linux PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin" and bash: line 21: rm: command not found. So I am on a git bash session?Now do I need to include rm.exe? Note: Second line of my code rm -rf temp did worked.

Comment: @Saran Could you add to your PATH `/bin`? `rm` should be in `/bin`. Add `export PATH=$PATH:/bin`

Comment: Thanks much. It worked. I updated the default path in order to add java_home but then other commands failed. By including /bin as you said. It's working as expected.